# Webmatrix - Locking down page

Tags: security, webmatrix, helper

I have a page where users can modify their own records in my database. This works well, but i'm trying to tidy up all the security flaws. As you can see from the code below, This page gets data using a querystring parameters. At the moment, anyone can change this query string and edit any record.

How do i incorporate a check using the "RequireAuthenticatedUser" and the matching UserID field in the PropertyInfo table?

Current code:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];

var Propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0";
var qPropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(Propertyinfo, rPropertyId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your PropertyInfo table also holds the property owner's user ID? If so, just include it in the WHERE clause and pass in the `CurrentUserId` value:

```
var PropertyInfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyId = @0 AND UserId = @1";
var qPropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(Propertyinfo, rPropertyId, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```